# Always on basic question

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to find this on Google but no love. Usually that means it's so basic everyone else knows it. But I would like an answer for my own peace of mind.

If I make a change to one server in an Always On situation - like say adding an index - do I have to make the same change to the other server? And if I do, is there a risk of the two servers not being in sync?

Any links to articles would be fine. Just want to be certain.

TIA

Comment: If you add Index on Always on Primary when both servers are in SYNC no need to add it again.. For more info check https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/careful-adding-indexes-with-alwayson-availability-groups/.. Google always helps :)

Answer (score 3):

> If I make a change to one server in an Always On situation - like say adding an index - do I have to make the same change to the other server?

No, you just make the change to Primary (master replica) database which is writable. Rest other databases in an availability group are either read only or not accessible depending on if you have opened your secondary replicas for read or not.

> And if I do, is there a risk of the two servers not being in sync?

If the replica sync mode is set to Synchronous then it will always be in sync. If it is set to Async, then there it might lag a bit. In my experience, unless you have a very high latency, its always near to instantaneous for async replicas as well.

for few concepts, [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/04/22/how-it-works-always-onwhen-is-my-secondary-failover-ready/) is very detailed info that you will find on how it works.